# To call a spring security protected API

Tags: java, spring

I have a user with username foo and password foo.

In my spring security protected Rest API. There is one controller as follow

```
@PostMapping("/mypath")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody String username) throws Exception {
  //save the username
}
```

How can invoke this API from controller in another spring project? As I only know how to test with Postman. I am not sure where to enter the username and password. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try Spring RestTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna look at `WebClient` or `RestTemplate`

Maybe something like:

```java
webClient.post()
    .uri("/mypath")
    .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(userName, password))
    .retrieve();
```